# How can I solve this absolute value logarithmic inequality?

Tags: inequality, logarithms, examples-counterexamples

I am trying to solve the following inequality: I would like to show that the absolute value of $1- r \ln (1- \frac 1 r)+ \ln ⁡(1- \frac 1 r)$ is less than $1.$  I already know that $r$ is greater than $0,$ and for this equation to be defined I know that $r$ is greater than $1.$  I can't seem to get anywhere when attempting to prove this.  Any help is appreciated. Also apologies for not knowing how to format the equation to look nice on here.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: WolframAlpha [reports](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+%7C1-+x*ln+(1-1%2Fx)%2B+ln%E2%81%A1(1-1%2Fx)%7C%3C1) "no real solutions".

Answer (score 1):

It's wrong. For example, try $r=2$.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the case where $r$ is large and use Taylor expansion to get
$$1-r \log \left(1-\frac{1}{r}\right)+\log \left(1-\frac{1}{r}\right)=2-\frac{1}{2 r}-\frac{1}{6 r^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{r^3}\right)$$

**Edit**

After Yves Daoust's good comment, using the infinite series
$$1-r \log \left(1-\frac{1}{r}\right)+\log \left(1-\frac{1}{r}\right)=2-\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n(n+1)r^n}$$

Comment: Hi Claude. This is a nice, compact approach. Anyway, a Big-O term in the expression doesn't prevent it to exceed $2$ for some finite $r$.

Comment: @YvesDaoust. Good point ! I added the infinite summation. Moreover, we can study the function the first and second  derivatives being always positive.

Answer (score 0):

If you simplify it you can see that there is no value for $r$ so that the inequality holds:
$|1-r\ln(1-1/r)+\ln(1-1/r)| <1=|1+(r-1)\ln(r/r-1)| < 1$, then:

$-1 < 1+(r-1)\ln(r/r-1) <1$, then from right inequality you will obtain:

$(r-1)\ln(r/r-1) < 0$ since r is positive $r-1$ should be positive as well because of the domain of the function $\ln$. So $r>1$. On the other hand, $r/r-1 <1$ so that the inequality $(r-1)\ln(r/r-1)$ becomes negative (or satisfied) which gives 0 < -1 which is a contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

From the well-known inequality $\ln t\le t-1$, we draw

$$\color{green}{1+(r-1)\ln\frac r{r-1}\le}1+(r-1)\left(\frac r{r-1}-1\right)=\color{green}2.$$

This value is reached at infinity, so the bound is tight.